# Opencart - Any way to let customers change their own Customer Group?

Tags: opencart

Opencart supports the ability for people to choose their Customer Group when they create their account.  However, it doesn't appear there's any way for a user to then change that setting once the account is created.

I've searched everywhere I can think of and haven't found any instructions on how to do this.  Anyone know how I might be able to add that in?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know, but unless You come up with Your own not working solution I cannot help You (this question is generally considered **off-topic**). Or contact me, I can do this for You for money.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this isn't something you can change a couple of lines with and it be enabled. You'll need to add it to a view, create the controller methods including validation and create a method in a model to update the group via SQL.